# Cross Compiling PALSIADE for android

Tags: android, c++, cross-compiling, palisade

we are trying to build PALISADE (https://git.njit.edu/palisade/PALISADE) for Android. We have made some Progress by building “gmp” and “ntl” successfully for Android.

GMP is able to cross compile out of the box. NTL was a bit more tricky. We used https://github.com/nemirst/ntl-android but changed the headers and src to the version provided within PALISADE (10.5.0)

We also did some changes to the PALISADE makefiles so they support cross compiling using the android standalone toolchains. The issue is now, when trying to compile PALISADE using the cross compiled NTL and GMP lib we get the following errors:

```
PALISADE/bin/build/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android/bin/aarch64-linux-android-gcc --sysroot=PALISADE/bin/build/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android/sysroot -g -Wall -Werror -O3 -fopenmp -pthread -I src -Isrc/core/lib -Isrc/pke/lib -Isrc/abe/lib -Isrc/signature/lib -I test -I /opt/local/include/libomp -fopenmp -I third-party/include -I third-party/include/rapidjson -c -o bin/build/core/lib/math/benative-math-impl.o src/core/lib/math/benative-math-impl.cpp
In file included from src/core/lib/math/benative-math-impl.cpp:28:
In file included from src/core/lib/utils/../math/backend.h:43:
src/core/lib/math/native_int/binint.h:956:79: error: no viable conversion from 'const unsigned long' to 'NTL::wide_double'
                return (uint_type)NTL::MulModPrecon(this->m_value,b.m_value,modulus.m_value,bInv.m_value);
                                                                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
src/core/lib/math/transfrm.cpp:192:33: note: in instantiation of member function 'native_int::NativeInteger<unsigned long>::ModMulPreconOptimized' requested here
                                                        InputToFFT[i]=element[i].ModMulPreconOptimized((*rootOfUnityTable)[i],modulus,preconTable[i]);
                                                                                 ^
third-party/include/NTL/sp_arith.h:405:4: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const unsigned long' to 'const NTL::wide_double &' for 1st argument
   wide_double(const wide_double& x) : data(x.data) { }
   ^
third-party/include/NTL/sp_arith.h:812:62: note: passing argument to parameter 'bninv' here
inline long MulModPrecon(long a, long b, long n, wide_double bninv)
                                                             ^
In file included from src/core/lib/math/benative-math-impl.cpp:36:
src/core/lib/math/transfrm.cpp:107:48: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 4, have 5
                                preconRootOfUnityInverseTable, cycloOrder, ans);
                                                                           ^~~
src/core/lib/math/transfrm.cpp:300:38: note: in instantiation of member function 'lbcrypto::NumberTheoreticTransform<native_int::NativeVector<native_int::NativeInteger<unsigned long> > >::InverseTransformIterative' requested here
                NumberTheoreticTransform<VecType>::InverseTransformIterative(element, *rootOfUnityITable,
                                                   ^
src/core/lib/math/transfrm.h:67:3: note: 'ForwardTransformIterative' declared here
                static void ForwardTransformIterative(const VecType& element, const VecType &rootOfUnityTable, const usint cycloOrder, VecType* result) {
                ^
In file included from src/core/lib/math/benative-math-impl.cpp:28:
In file included from src/core/lib/utils/../math/backend.h:43:
src/core/lib/math/native_int/binint.h:975:88: error: no viable conversion from 'const unsigned long' to 'NTL::wide_double'
                this->m_value = (uint_type)NTL::MulModPrecon(this->m_value,b.m_value,modulus.m_value,bInv.m_value);
                                                                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
src/core/lib/math/transfrm.cpp:313:21: note: in instantiation of member function 'native_int::NativeInteger<unsigned long>::ModMulPreconOptimizedEq' requested here
                                                        (*OpIFFT)[i].ModMulPreconOptimizedEq((*rootOfUnityITable)[i],nativeModulus,preconTable[i]);
                                                                     ^
third-party/include/NTL/sp_arith.h:405:4: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const unsigned long' to 'const NTL::wide_double &' for 1st argument
   wide_double(const wide_double& x) : data(x.data) { }
   ^
third-party/include/NTL/sp_arith.h:812:62: note: passing argument to parameter 'bninv' here
inline long MulModPrecon(long a, long b, long n, wide_double bninv)
                                                             ^
3 errors generated.
make[1]: *** [bin/build/core/lib/math/benative-math-impl.o] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

We would greatly appreciate any help in getting this library to build for Android.

EDIT: Spelling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little late in response, but if you are still interested, newer versions of Palisade do not require GMP or NTL (those are only enabled when the user explicitly enables them in the CMake build process), so it may be easier to build now. You should be using the newest stable version at https://gitlab.com/palisade/palisade-release or if you are willing to try it out, the development version at https://gitlab.com/palisade/palisade-development

Cross compiling is a bit tricky, but it can be done. We are working on some embedded targets but they are not yet in the release stream.

We are looking into supporting an Android port in a future release, so any progress you make that you can share with us is most appreciated.
Dave Cousins -- PALISADE Development team.

Comment: We actually got the 1.5 Version to compile for android (at least for the arm64 and x86_64 variants). GMP wasn't really an issue and after some work we got NTL to work. Will definitely check out the newer version without GMP / NTL when I get to it. The changes to the actual PALISADE build was rather minor. Feel free to contact me if you want more information on what we did (it was a test project, so none of the changes are production ready).